# Laravel 5.5 : Throttle middeware change values

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

I am trying to change throttle time in controller based on a condition.
Here is the controller code :

Here is the middleware in constructor :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('throttle');
}
```

Here is the

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {

    $this->middleware('throttle:200,5'); // here i am changing the time
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}
```

**What i basically want is that if user attempts get to the point, Then by default laravel is locking out a user for one minute, But on second throttle i want to increase that time from one minute to some other time Lets say 3 minutes.**

*But its not changing. What am i missing. It locks me down to one minute again, Which should be now more the 3 minutes*

Comment: I think you should read handle() method of throttle middleware may be this will help you.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad It should set with the above code, But its not setting the values.

Comment: you need to go look into what the `middleware` method does on controllers, all it does is set an array element ... you are not 'adding' a new middleware to anything, they don't work this way ... the middleware stack has already been built and the request has been dispatched through it, you cant add or alter it at this point at all, if you are at the controller method you have already passed through the stack

Comment: @lagbox The code is on `LoginController`, I am setting the values to the middleware on condition of `tooManyAttempts`, And in my head, It should set, But its not.

Comment: @lagbox I checked the passed values there, Its going, I checked it via `dd(parameters...);`. It gets there.

Comment: what 'passed value' what are you talking about?   calling `middleware` in that if statement is doing NOTHING, i dont know how else to tell you this

Comment: @lagbox Okay if statement is doing nothing, Then how will i be able to change the throttle time dynamically ?

Comment: why are you assiging the `throttle` middleware at all?  the `login` route has its own internal limiter, that is how it can lockout the login, its not using any middleware ... the `throttle` middleware is based on requests, the login lockout is based on attempting to `login` .. they are different things